# jQuery smooth scroll doesn't change URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

Everything is working as it should, however the URL does not change when the jQuery is in place. Is there anyway to have it smooth scroll and change the url at the same time? I tried a different method before this however it wasn't as cross browser compatible as this.

My HTML is:

```
<li class="representing-you-online"><a href="#representing-you-online">Representing you online</a></li>
<li class="developing-your-people"><a href="#developing-your-people">Developing your people</a></li>
```

My jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          if (target.length == 0) target = $('a[name="' + this.hash.substr(1) + '"]');
          if (target.length == 0) target = $('html');
          $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top }, 500);
          return false;
      });
  });
$(document).ready(function(){      
        $('#logo a').click(function () {
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the click handling code for your anchors like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        var hash = this.hash;
        if (target.length == 0) target = $('a[name="' + this.hash.substr(1) + '"]');
        if (target.length == 0) target = $('html');
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top }, 500, function (){
            location.hash = hash;
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Please note the complete function in the end of the jquery .animate(). It changes the URL.

See the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g6QCP/2/show/).